# What can we learn from Matrix video games?

Tags: the-matrix

So far I only watched Animatrix and the Matrix series and I heard that the video games also carry a lot of information about Matrix's inner workings. What are the key facts that one wouldn't know about the series without playing the games?

Comment: Hello. I've VTC because I think this is too broad. You could for example tell us what games you're including or not in your question.

Comment: If you want a broad outline, just read the Matrix wiki articles about the individual games listed at http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_Video_Games (The Matrix Online in particular)

Comment: “What can we learn from Matrix video games?” — Mainly, we learn to buy other, better games instead.

Comment: If I narrowed it down to only information directly related to the movies, would this question be eligible for reopening?

Comment: @d33tah imagine this: even if you were asking for the 'top 5' elements to be learned from "the games", their order of importance would be open to interpretation to some degree. That said, I'd attempt to reword it as something like "On what points the games extend the Matrix franchise's storyline?" and/or "What character development in the Matrix games contribute to the plot?", etc. (focusing on themes by your current point of interest). Aside from that, take note that arguably only Enter the Matrix would suitably meet one's expectations of considerable added information.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a number of years since I played the game. But it was meant to be played during the two movies to interlink the story, along with the animatrix.

The problem was if you hadn't seen the movies then a lot of it didn't make sense.

As for the parts that were described in more detail in the game.

- Starts off where the end of the Animatrix (related to the Osiris ship).
- Why the heads of the ships were in the Matrix for a meeting.
- How Agent Smith managed to infect a human.
- Who blew up the power plant in the movie.
- More details on who the Key maker is.
- Who the Merovingian actually is.
- More details on Matrix v1 + v2 and why they failed.
- Why the Oracle changed into a new person (Original actress died between movies, so reason had to be written in).

May be more.

Comment: nitpick: it's actually the "`Keymaker`", *not* the "`Key master`"

Comment: @naxa fixed. For future reference, I have no issue people correcting my answers. :)